# SQL Pivot/Unpivot similar column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

```sql
drop table if exists tbl
go
create table tbl(
refId int,
refNm varchar(10),
prodID_0 int,
prodNm_0 varchar(10),
prodDesc_0 VARCHAR(10),
prodID_1 int,
prodNm_1 varchar(10),
prodDesc_1 VARCHAR(10),
prodID_2 int,
prodNm_2 varchar(10),
prodDesc_2 VARCHAR(10)
)

insert into tbl values
(1,'aaa',11,'aaa_1_1','Prod 1_1',21,'bbb_2_1','Prod 2_1',31,'ccc_3_1','Prod 3_1'),
(2,'bbb',22,'bbb_2_2','Prod 2_2',23,'bbb_2_2','Prod 2_2',34,'ccc_3_2','Prod 3_2'),
(3,'ccc',33,'ccc_3_3','Prod 3_3',24,'bbb_2_3','Prod 2_3',35,'ccc_3_3','Prod 3_3')

select * from tbl:
```

| refId | refNm | prodID_0 | prodNm_0 | prodDesc_0 | prodID_1 | prodNm_1 | prodDesc_1 | prodID_2 | prodNm_2 | prodDesc_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 11 | aaa_1_1 | Prod 1_1 | 21 | bbb_2_1 | Prod 2_1 | 31 | ccc_3_1 | Prod 3_1 |
| 2 | bbb | 22 | bbb_2_2 | Prod 2_2 | 23 | bbb_2_2 | Prod 2_2 | 34 | ccc_3_2 | Prod 3_2 |
| 3 | ccc | 33 | ccc_3_3 | Prod 3_3 | 24 | bbb_2_3 | Prod 2_3 | 35 | ccc_3_3 | Prod 3_3 |

I tried to unpivot but it wasn't giving me the desired results.

How can I get the output below, based on the table above:

| refId | refNm | prodID | prodNm | prodDesc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 11 | aaa_1_1 | Prod 1_1 |
| 1 | aaa | 21 | bbb_2_1 | Prod 2_1 |
| 1 | aaa | 31 | ccc_3_1 | Prod 3_1 |
| 2 | bbb | 22 | bbb_2_2 | Prod 2_2 |
| 2 | bbb | 23 | bbb_2_2 | Prod 2_2 |
| 2 | bbb | 34 | ccc_3_2 | Prod 3_2 |
| 3 | ccc | 33 | ccc_3_3 | Prod 3_3 |
| 3 | ccc | 24 | bbb_2_3 | Prod 2_3 |
| 3 | ccc | 35 | ccc_3_3 | Prod 3_3 |

Comment: I *hope* the reason you want to achieve this is to fix your design. If it isn't, make it so that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by manual pivot:

```sql
select refid, refnm, unpvt.*
from #tbl l
cross apply (
    values  (prodid_0, prodnm_0, proddesc_0)
    ,   (prodid_1, prodnm_1, proddesc_1)
    ,   (prodid_2, prodnm_2, proddesc_2)
    ) unpvt(prodid, prodNm, proddesc)
```

For every row in #tbl this creates 3 rows with columns lined up by their counters.

Edit, dynamic sql version:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select  @sql =  N'
select refid, refnm, unpvt.*
from #tbl l
cross apply (
    values  ' + 
    STRING_AGG('(' + name + ',' + 'prodnm_' + substring(name, charindex('_', name) + 1, 999) + ',' + 'proddesc_' + substring(name, charindex('_', name) + 1, 999) + ')', ',')
    + N'
) unpvt(prodid, prodNm, proddesc)
    '
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns sc -- change this to your database 
where   object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tbl') -- change this name for real table
and name like 'prodid[_]%'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: @siggermannen Thanks for your prompt response....but the actual columns stretches up between prod_200 and prod_300...is there a way to make the VALUES clause more dynamic

Comment: Well, then you need to add that info in your question :) If you know dynamic sql, i think it should be pretty simple to generate the string similar to above that goes to 300 or whatever

Comment: @siggermannen The dynamic SQL does solve it....Many Thanks

Comment: `QUOTENAME` would be wise